# In HTML, the formatting of a table is messed up

Tags: html, html-table, formatting

To see what the table looks like now go to [http://www.atsbusinessandgames.co.cc/Downloads/External-Video-Downloads/](http://atsbusinessandgames.co.cc/Downloads/External-Video-Downloads/).

If you look you will notice that some sections are missing completly or misplaced even though they are cleardefined within the code. Here is the code for the table:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="8">
<tr>
<th>Movie Name</th>
<th>Code</th>
<th>Link</th>
<th>File Size</th>
<th>Genre</th>
<th>Addition Info</th>
<th>Plot Summery</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cars</td> <!--movie name -->
<td>V,G</td> <!-- Code -- >
<td>http://www.watchthisfree.com/movies/2006/cars/watch/</td> <!-- link -- >
<td>265.3mb</td> <!-- File Size -->
<td>Coming Soon</td> <!--Genre -->
<td>Once the page loads click play video then click play again. The RealPlayer downloader should come up. Download the video using this.
Do not use or click any links on the page. The download video link and the download VLC Media Player are both known virus links.
I don't recommend clicking anything on this page.</td> <!--Addition Info-->
<td>Coming Soon</td> <!--Plot Summery -->
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Fly Away Home</td> <!--movie name -->
<td>None</td> <!-- Code -- >
<td>Coming Soon</td> <!-- link -- >
<td>Coming Soon</td> <!-- File Size -->
<td>Coming Soon</td> <!--Genre -->
<td>Coming Soon</td> <!--Addition Info-->
<td>Coming Soon</td> <!--Plot Summery -->
</tr>

<tr>
<td>The Social Network</td> <!--movie name -->
<td>V,G</td> <!-- Code -- >
<td>http://www.watchthisfree.com/movies/2010/the-social-network/watch/</td> <!-- link -- >
<td>742mb</td> <!-- File Size -->
<td>Coming Soon</td>  <!--Genre -->
<td>Once the page loads click play video then click play again. The RealPlayer downloader should come up. Download the video using this.
Do not use or click any links on the page. The download video link and the download VLC Media Player are both known virus links.
I don't recommend clicking anything on this page.</td>  <!--Addition Info-->
<td>Coming Soon</td>  <!--Plot Summery -->
</tr>

</table>

</center>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated since I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Perhaps it's the comment on some lines which is not correctly closed (-- > instead of -->)

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fatsbusinessandgames.co.cc%2FDownloads%2FExternal-Video-Downloads%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a couple places you have `<!-- Comment -- >` but the comment isn't terminating because your `--` isn't attached to the `>`. Look at your post and see where the syntax highlighting has greyed out the commented parts to see which areas to correct.

Comment: Thank you. I din't realize that. Make a mistake once copy it 50 times.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces between the end of your HTML comment tags:

```
-- >
```

should be

```
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

After a test over here, it's clear that the table-cells are missing because of the invalid comment closing tags.

You're using:

```
<td>Coming Soon</td> <!-- link -- >
```

There is a space too much at the end between - and >

Answer (score 1):

remove your comment. it not on the right format. you do not close comment properly.
please remove space between -- and >